# How to install and use NatTable?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans, nattable

I have developed some web applications before and everything is well documented and there is a framework for anything. I am new to Swing and desktop application development and I found that documentation is sparse and you have to figure out a lot of things by experimenting.

I've been googling for a few hours on how to setup [NatTable](http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/) and I couldn't find anything. I was surprised no one asked the question before. I just want some instructions on how to get the basics working on Eclipse and NetBeans. I was using Eclipse in the past but I think I will use NetBeans for this project as the Swing GUI editor is better.

Is NatTable exclusive to Eclipse or will it also work with NetBeans? If someone can post screenshots of the setup procedure, that would be awesome.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think Netbeans can support SWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NatTable project has a website that contains some information. It doesn't cover everything, but how to install and use it is explained:
https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=getting_started

Currently NatTable is building a SWT control. Swing is not supported. That might change in the future.